# MySQL order by first column, sorted by second column

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, datetime, sql-order-by

I'm trying to get the correct `ORDER BY` for my MySQL query, however I can't get the order by correct.

I have two columns:

1. `breaking_news` = values are `NULL` or `1`
2. `news_published_dt` = values are `DATETIME`

How can I sort so that the first output are `breaking_news NOT NULL`  sorted by `DATETIME`, and then the rest afterwards is just ordered by `DATETIME`?

I've tried this, but it gave me no output

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN n.breaking_news IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, n.news_published_dt DESC
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM tableName ORDER BY breaking_news DESC, news_published_dt ASC (**UPDATED**)

Comment: @MalikAsif Worked, thanks! :) Please post answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like, you are looking for this:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    tableName 
ORDER BY 
    breaking_news DESC, 
    news_published_dt ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY news_published_dt DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from 
(select *, 1 Shortby from table 1 where (breaking_news is null)
union all
select *, 2 Shortby from table 1 where (breaking_news=1)
) a
order by Shortby ,news_published_dt Desc
```

Answer (score 0):

SORT BY in MySQL works differently than what you (me included) would be expected.  You cannot do a sort by of two columns and have each of the first sorted by columns sorted according to the second.

DOES NOT WORK:

```
ORDER BY breaking_news, news_published_dt
```

RESULT:

```
breaking_news | news_published_dt
            1 | 2019-04-17
            1 | 2019-04-04
         null | 2019-05-01
         null | 2019-05-06
```

- Notice that the nulls are sorted correctly, however where breaking_news is 1; the results are not sorted according to what the poster wants.

The only way that I have found to accomplish this; query for the wanted boolean result individually and then union the two together.

THIS DOES WORK:

```
(SELECT * FROM news_table WHERE breaking_news = 1 ORDER BY news_published_dt)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM news_table WHERE breaking_news <> 1 ORDER BY news_published_dt)
```

RESULT:

```
breaking_news | news_published_dt
            1 | 2019-04-04
            1 | 2019-04-17
         null | 2019-05-01
         null | 2019-05-06
```

For a more thorough explanation of this, check out [Edwin Wang's explanation](https://blog.pythian.com/mysql-may-return-results-in-non-deterministic-order-with-order-by/)

Answer (score -2):

USE This 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN n.breaking_news IS NOT NULL THEN n.breaking_news ELSE 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz' END, n.news_published_dt DESC